# catchfile(betweentags) and obeylines

Tags: environments, input

I'm writing two large documents, both containing much of the same text.

To ease the maintenance, I'd like no redundant paragraphs, but rather to use catchfilebetweentags.

Everything works well, except that catchfilebetweentags (Or possibly catchfile) break the obeylines enviornment.

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\ExecuteMetaData[getfromthisfile.tex]{getthissection}

\begin{obeylines}
  Line 1
  Line 2
\end{obeylines}

\end{document}
```

And the file to catch from, getfromthisfile.tex

```
%<*getthissection>
\begin{obeylines}
  Line 1
  Line 2
\end{obeylines}
%</getthissection>
```

The resulting document:

```
Line 1Line 2
Line 1
Line 2
```

This obviously also apply to other environments using obeylines.

Any workarounds or suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

There is no documented `obeylines` environment; the fact that it somehow works doesn't mean it's safe in the context you're trying to use it.

What `\obeylines` does is changing the category code of the end-of-line character (usually 5) to 13 (active character) and, roughly speaking, definining this active character to issue `\par`.

However this works only when the input file is read in to be typeset. With `catchfilebetweentags` you can get the four lines, but the end-of-line characters have already been converted to spaces before `\obeylines` can act.

This has to do with how TeX reads characters from files in order to transform it into its favorite food called “tokens”.

There is another problem: `catchfilebetweentags.sty` plays with the `\endlinechar` parameter, so even the space corresponding to the end-of-line is mangled. Which is to be considered a bug in the package.